# How do I create a class to make multiple toplevels of one main window in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter

I want to create a program where I can create a main window and it's multiple toplevels , using classes . However , when I run my code given below , it creates 'multiple main windows and multiple toplevels' and not 'one main window and multiple toplevels' . Can anyone please recommend me how can I do this ?

```
from tkinter import *

class tk_window:
    def __init__(self, root, exit_button):
        self.root = root
        self.exit_button = exit_button

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('500x500')

        self.exit_button = Button(self.root, text='EXIT', command=self.root.destroy)
        self.exit_button.place(x=0, y=0)
        
        Label(self.root, text='Vk').place(x=100, y=100)

class tk_toplevel(tk_window):
    def __init__(self, top_level, root, exit_button):
        super().__init__(root, exit_button)
        self.top_level = top_level
        self.exit_button = exit_button

        self.top_level = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.exit_button = Button(self.top_level, text='EXIT', command=self.top_level.destroy)
        self.exit_button.place(x=0, y=0)

root2 = tk_toplevel('top_level1', 'root', 'exit_button1')
root3 = tk_toplevel('top_level2', 'root', 'exit_button2')
root4 = tk_toplevel('top_level3', 'root', 'exit_button3')
root5 = tk_toplevel('top_level4', 'root', 'exit_button4')

root1 = tk_window('root', 'exit_button')

root1.root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get multiple main windows because your top-level inherits from the main window. Thus, every instance of `tk_toplevel` *is a* `tk_window`, and also creates an instance of `Toplevel`.

If you don't want more than one `tk_window`, don't create a class that inherits from it. Instead, just inherit from `Toplevel` and then don't create a separate instance of `Toplevel`

```
class tk_toplevel(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, top_level, root, exit_button):
        super().__init__(root, exit_button)
        self.top_level = top_level
        self.exit_button = exit_button

        self.exit_button = Button(self, text='EXIT', command=self.destroy)
        self.exit_button.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Also, you should pass in the actual root window, not a string that is the same as the name of the root window.

```
root2 = tk_toplevel('top_level1', root, 'exit_button1')
root3 = tk_toplevel('top_level2', root, 'exit_button2')
root4 = tk_toplevel('top_level3', root, 'exit_button3')
root5 = tk_toplevel('top_level4', root, 'exit_button4')
```

---

Unrelated to the question being asked, you should read the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming guidelines. It will make your code easier to understand. For your code that means to start your class names with an uppercase character.